# std::hex cannot process negative numbers?

Tags: c++, hex, iomanip

I'm trying to use std::hex to read hexadecimal integers from a file.

```
0
a
80000000
...
```

These integers are both positive and negative.

It seems that std::hex cannot handle negative numbers. I don't understand why, and I don't see a range defined in the docs.

Here is a test bench:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main () {

  int i;
  std::stringstream ss;

  // This is the smallest number
  // That can be stored in 32 bits -1*2^(31)
  ss << "80000000";

  ss >> std::hex >> i;

  std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
7fffffff
```

Comment: How is it supposed to know that the hex number is signed? 0x80000000 will overflow the `int`, assuming 32 bit `int`, and after that all bets are off. Well maybe not in C++ 20, but I haven't done much with 20 yet.

Comment: @user4581301 I guess I want std::hex to infer that the number is negative, because it is reading into a 32 bit int.

Comment: I guess the solution is to read into unsigned int, and then cast to signed.

Comment: No good information on cppreference and I can't find anything in the Standard that states hex is anything but unsigned. It just sets the base used for conversion to 16 and walks away.

Comment: Side note: In C, the `%x` format argument is explicitly unsigned (same with `%o`).

Comment: @user4581301 thank you very much, if you want to put these comments into an answer, I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `std::hex` tells the stream to read integer tokens [as though using `std::scanf` with the `%X` formatter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get). [`%X` reads into an unsigned integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), and the resulting value would overflow an `int` even through the bit pattern fits. Because of the overflow, the read fails, and the contents of `i` cannot be trusted to hold the expected value. Side note: `i` will be set to 0 if compiling to C++11 or more recent or unchanged from its current unspecified value before c++11.

Note that if we check the stream state after the read, something you should ALWAYS do, we can see that the read failed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint> // added for fixed width integers.
int main () {

  int32_t i; //ensure 32 bit int
  std::stringstream ss;

  // This is the smallest number
  // That can be stored in 32 bits -1*2^(31)
  ss << "80000000";

  if (ss >> std::hex >> i)
  {
      std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "FAIL! " <<  std::endl; //will execute this
  }
}
```

The solution is, as the asker surmised in the comments to read into an `unsigned int` (`uint32_t` to avoid further surprises if `int` is not 32 bits). The following is the zero-surprises version of the code using `memcpy` to transfer the exact bit pattern read into `i`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint> // added for fixed width integers.
#include <cstring> //for memcpy
int main () {

  int32_t i; //ensure 32 bit int
  std::stringstream ss;

  // This is the smallest number
  // That can be stored in 32 bits -1*2^(31)
  ss << "80000000";

  uint32_t temp;
  if (ss >> std::hex >> temp)
  {
      memcpy(&i, &temp, sizeof(i));// probably compiles down to cast
      std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "FAIL! " <<  std::endl; 
  }
}
```

That said, diving into old-school C-style coding for a moment

```cpp
  if (ss >> std::hex >> *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&i))
  {
    std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "FAIL! " <<  std::endl; 
  }
```

violates [the strict aliasing rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), but I'd be stunned to see it fail once 32 bit `int` is forced with `int32_t i;`. This might even be legal in more recent C++ Standards as being "Type Similar", but I'm still wrapping my head around that.